# How do I provide a filter for the initial results in the ContactPicker?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using the built in ContactPicker with the Phone.CONTENT_URI to build a list of contacts that the user selects. So far it's worked pretty well, but I would love to have it not show contacts my user has already selected.

I didn't think it was possible until just recently when I noticed my quick contacts widget manages to filter the list before displaying it - ensuring I only see contacts I haven't selected.

Does anyone know how to do this? Right now my implementation is just a simple:

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Phone.CONTENT_URI);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is a documented way of achieving what you seek. Sorry!